# Como depurar PHP pelo Sublime Text 3?

Tags: php, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, xdebug

Qual o processo para *depurar* **PHP** pelo **Sublime Text 3**?

Li em alguns lugares que deve se utilizar o *Xdebug*, mas a maioria dos procedimentos que vi não funcionaram.

Obs.: Meu Sistema é **Ubuntu** e estou utilizando **PHP 7**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim você pode utilizar o Xdebug.
Basta instalar o xdebug em seu sistema
Depois no sublime instale o package xdebug-client 
Pronto depois é só adicionar os breakpoints
Segue um link de instalação e configuração:
[Xdebug Sublime 3](https://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-xdebug-sublime-text-3/)